# IAM: CloudFormation:GetTemplateSummary not allowed by user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

right now I am getting an error that says `CloudFormation:GetTemplateSummary` is not allowed to user.

Admin users have permission to general new stacks from CF, but the non-admin user in question does not.

What IAM role will allow a user to create a stack from a cloudformation template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no readymade role for this. You can create a policy to describe and create stacks. Then attach the policy to the user or the group the user is in. In the following policy, `CreateStack` action lets an user create a stack. Others are read only actions which you can choose to keep or remove selectively.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplate",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary",
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you, that mostly worked. I had to add a couple additional fields: `cloudformation:UpdateStack`, `cloudformation:DeleteStack`, and `cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary`